# Angular.js $Resource service action methods

Tags: angularjs, rest, parameters, optional-parameters

I was going through the angularJS $Resource service documentation and I came across something strange.
(https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

There are some custom action methods and you can also define your own. Then, these methods can be called with the following parameters:

```
HTTP GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], [success], [error])
non-GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], postData, [success], [error])
```

But then, later in the example, a default action method:

```
'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true}
```

is called like this:

```
var CreditCard = $resource('/user/:userId/card/:cardId',
  {userId:123, cardId:'@id'}, {
   charge: {method:'POST', params:{charge:true}}
  });

var cards = CreditCard.query(function() {
  // GET: /user/123/card
  // server returns: [ {id:456, number:'1234', name:'Smith'} ];
   var card = cards[0];
   ...
});
```

As you can see, the first parameter of the query method is the success callback function (at least, that's what I'm assuming this is) instead of the [parameters] param.
I'd expect:

```
var cards = CreditCard.query({}, function() { ... });
```

Am I missing something or can you simply omit the first parameter if you don't need it?

I know this is kind of a silly question but I want to make sure I'm not getting it wrong here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `[]` bracket in the `Resource.action([parameters], [success], [error])` mean that those parameters are optional and could be omitted.

But that doesn't tell what will happen if only a single callback is passed as a parameters and you would think:

Will it be considered as a `[parameters]` or `[success]` or `[error]`, since those are all optional, not even count the `postData` for a non-GET action.

I'm not sure if this is mentioned anywhere in the documentation. But to clear things up, lets explore the angularjs source code and you will find the exact logic for that.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.21/src/ngResource/resource.js#L470

And here are all the combination that valid for a `GET` request.

```
// 4 arguments
params, data, success(), error() 

// 3 arguments
params, data, success()
params, success(), error()

// 2 arguments
params, success()
success(), error()

// 1 argument
success()
params
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can omit the first parameter if you don't want to pass any parameters with your request. As stated in the documentation:

> The action methods on the class object or instance object can be
>   invoked with the following parameters:
>
> HTTP GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], [success],
>   [error])

The `[]` bracket notation implies that it is optional, so if "parameters" is not provided then the value expected are success and error callbacks.